# How do I get reputation with Argent Dawn?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

It looks to me like all the old methods (grinding/farming scourge stones, killing undead in the Plaguelands) don't work anymore.

Is there any way to raise reputation with the Argent Dawn faction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the old methods have indeed been removed as of Cataclysm. Instead, there are only three ways to increase reputation, as [described in Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Argent_Dawn#Reputation):

> Players can obtain Revered reputation with the Argent Dawn by completing the Fiona's Caravan quests in the Eastern Plaguelands up through and including  [42] Argent Call: The Trial of the Crypt. Completing this quest will bring the player to exactly 0/21000 Revered, unless they are already Revered (from performing Argent Dawn quests before the release of Cataclysm). After this point, the only way to continue obtaining Argent Dawn reputation is by performing the two repeatable quests  [42D] Aberrations of Bone and  [46D] Annals of the Silver Hand given by Lord Raymond George in the crypt behind Light's Hope Chapel. As of patch 4.1, these two quests reward 2200 reputation each.